# Are vector fields really sections of the tangent bundle?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-bundles, vector-fields, tangent-bundle, tangent-spaces

Let $(TM,M,\pi,F)$ be the tangent bundle on $M$. I've seen multiple resources state that a vector field on $M$ is a section in $\Gamma_{TM}(M)$ of the tangent bundle. A vector field is a map
$$\Phi:M\rightarrow \space ?$$
$$p\mapsto v$$
$$v\in T_pM$$
but a section is a right inverse of $\pi:TM\rightarrow M$, so a section is a map
$$\sigma:M\rightarrow TM$$
$$p\mapsto (p,v)$$
$$(p,v)\in TM.$$
$TM=\{(p,v)\vert \space p\in M\space\text {and}\space v\in T_pM\}$, but this can't be the codomain of a vector field because these element's aren't the vectors; they're point-vector ordered pairs.

How do we get around this? And how should vector fields be restated in a similar way?

Answer (score 3):

(Ok, probably I should elaborate a bit more).

You take either one approach:

Either you take the tangent bundle as

$$ TM = \bigcup_{p\in M} T_p M,$$

and then a vector fields will be the mapping given by $p\mapsto v_p$, where $v_p \in T_pM$. Or,

You take the definition of $TM$ as

$$TM = \{ (p,v)\vert \space p\in M\space\text {and}\space v\in T_pM\},$$

for this definition, a vector fields is really a mapping $p\mapsto (p, v_p)$.

Under the mapping $v_p \mapsto (p, v_p)$, as sets these two are the same.

To me the the first definition is much better: the second gives an impression that $M$ is always a subset (the zero section) of $TM$: this is true for tangent bundle, but is false for general fiber bundles.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct. This is a pretty standard definition - see, for example, [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle) where it is given at the start. Also, as the page notes, it should be a disjoint union and not just a union. This is important because things can "overlap"

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Probably I should elaborate a bit more, but my formula is exactly the first equality in your given wiki page. (No they cannot overlap. For $p \neq q$, $T_pM$ and $T_qM$ are by definition different sets)

Comment: @ArticChar But is it possible for $T_pM\cap T_qM \neq \emptyset$ ? Because for an element $v$ this intersection, the projection function wouldn't know to map $v$ to $p$ or $v$ to $q$, so $\pi$ would by definition not be a function.

Comment: Well, it really depends on what is the definition of $T_pM$. If the definition is given by [equivalent class of curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_the_velocity_of_curves), then by definition $T_pM$ and $T_qM$ are different objects.@CamWhite